# flume-ng - avro event delivery reliability

Tags: java, flume, flume-ng

I am using flume-ng to aggregate data produced by applications into a central location for processing. Producers publish events to a local HTTP source, which is then forwarded to collectors via an Avro sink. Collectors receive events from the Avro sink via an Avro source. All producers replicate events to both collectors.

I have noticed a few nuances in the wild that concern me, and I have not been able to fully understand the complete ramifications of my configuration via docs and surrounding information on flume-ng. Apple to apple comparison of event publication with producer indicates not all events arrive at the collector. Latency of events successfully delivered is higher than anticipated. Occasionally we see events landing at the front door of the collector hours behind schedule. We also get intermittent exceptions in both downstream and upstream flume-ng logs.

- Using file channels on the producer leads me to believe we are still durable, flume-ng will *eventually* get the events upstream (correct?).
- With the collectors leveraging memory channels are we exposing ourselves to data loss? If so, are there any techniques for determining how many events are lost, or at least how frequently they are lost?
- With the collector's transaction capacity lower than the producer, do issues arise?
- What are sane checkpoint intervals for file channels requiring guaranteed delivery? I assume the interval is how frequently flume-ng ensures events are on local disk (eg. based on my configuration I would expect a maximum 1s data loss in a power outage, etc).

Below are relevant snippets of each stage's flume-ng configuration as well as stack trace snippets. Wondering if anyone can shed some light on discrepancies in the configuration based on aforementioned questions (assuming there are any).

Upstream exceptions:

```
(org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyServer$NettyServerAvroHandler.channelClosed:209)  - Connection to /<ip address>:<port> disconnected.
(org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyServer$NettyServerAvroHandler.exceptionCaught:201)  - Unexpected exception from downstream.
```

Downstream exceptions:

```
(org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run:160)  - Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
org.apache.flume.EventDeliveryException: Failed to send events
        at org.apache.flume.sink.AbstractRpcSink.process(AbstractRpcSink.java:382)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
        at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.apache.flume.FlumeException: NettyAvroRpcClient { host: <producer ip>, port: <producer port> }: RPC connection error
        at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.connect(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:161)
        at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.connect(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:115)
        at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.configure(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:590)
        at org.apache.flume.api.RpcClientFactory.getInstance(RpcClientFactory.java:88)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.AvroSink.initializeRpcClient(AvroSink.java:127)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.AbstractRpcSink.createConnection(AbstractRpcSink.java:209)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.AbstractRpcSink.verifyConnection(AbstractRpcSink.java:269)
        at org.apache.flume.sink.AbstractRpcSink.process(AbstractRpcSink.java:339)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error connecting to /<producer ip>:<producer port>
        at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.getChannel(NettyTransceiver.java:261)
        at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.<init>(NettyTransceiver.java:203)
        at org.apache.avro.ipc.NettyTransceiver.<init>(NettyTransceiver.java:152)
        at org.apache.flume.api.NettyAvroRpcClient.connect(NettyAvroRpcClient.java:147)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:592)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.connect(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:396)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.processSelectedKeys(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:358)
        at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$Boss.run(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:274)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        ... 1 more
```

Producer configuration:

```
agent.sources.t1d.type     = HTTP
agent.sources.t1d.bind     = <source ip>
agent.sources.t1d.port     = <source port>
agent.sources.t1d.channels = c01 c02 c03
agent.sources.t1d.selector.type = replicating

agent.channels.c01.type               = FILE
agent.channels.c01.checkpointDir = /path/to/checkpoint1
agent.channels.c01.dataDirs = /path/to/data1
agent.channels.c01.capacity   = 4000000
agent.channels.c01.transactionCapacity = 10000
agent.channels.c01.checkpointInterval = 1000
agent.channels.c01.keep-alive = 3

agent.channels.c02.type               = FILE
agent.channels.c02.checkpointDir = /path/to/checkpoint2
agent.channels.c02.dataDirs = /path/to/data2
agent.channels.c02.capacity   = 4000000
agent.channels.c02.transactionCapacity = 10000
agent.channels.c02.checkpointInterval = 1000
agent.channels.c02.keep-alive = 3

agent.channels.c03.type               = FILE
agent.channels.c03.checkpointDir = /path/to/checkpoint3
agent.channels.c03.dataDirs = /path/to/data3
agent.channels.c03.capacity   = 4000000
agent.channels.c03.transactionCapacity = 10000
agent.channels.c03.checkpointInterval = 1000
agent.channels.c03.keep-alive = 3

agent.sinks.s01.type          = AVRO
agent.sinks.s01.hostname      = <collector ip>
agent.sinks.s01.port          = <collector port>
agent.sinks.s01.channel       = c01
agent.sinks.s01.batch-size    = 1000
agent.sinks.s01.compression-type  = deflate
agent.sinks.s01.compression-level = 5

agent.sinks.s02.type          = AVRO
agent.sinks.s02.hostname      = <collector ip>
agent.sinks.s02.port          = <collector port>
agent.sinks.s02.channel       = c02
agent.sinks.s02.batch-size    = 1000
agent.sinks.s02.compression-type  = deflate
agent.sinks.s02.compression-level = 5

agent.sinks.s03.type         = FILE_ROLL
agent.sinks.s03.channel      = c03
agent.sinks.s03.sink.directory = /path/to/producer/reconciliation
agent.sinks.s03.sink.rollInterval = 1200
```

Collector A configuration:

```
agent.sources.a.type     = avro
agent.sources.a.bind     = <source ip>
agent.sources.a.port     = <source port>
agent.sources.a.channels = c01 c03
agent.sources.a.compression-type = deflate

agent.channels.c01.type   = memory
agent.channels.c01.capacity = 1000000
agent.channels.c01.transactionCapacity = 1000

agent.channels.c03.type   = memory
agent.channels.c03.capacity = 1000000
agent.channels.c03.transactionCapacity = 1000

agent.sinks.s01.type         = FILE_ROLL
agent.sinks.s01.channel      = c01
agent.sinks.s01.sink.directory = /path/to/storage/s01
agent.sinks.s01.sink.rollInterval = 300

agent.sinks.s03.type         = FILE_ROLL
agent.sinks.s03.channel      = c03
agent.sinks.s03.sink.directory = /path/to/storage/s03
agent.sinks.s03.sink.rollInterval = 300
```

Collector B configuration:

```
agent.sources.b.type     = avro
agent.sources.b.bind     = <source ip>
agent.sources.b.port     = <source port>
agent.sources.b.channels = c11 c13
agent.sources.b.compression-type = deflate

agent.channels.c11.type   = memory
agent.channels.c11.capacity = 1000000
agent.channels.c11.transactionCapacity = 1000

agent.channels.c13.type   = memory
agent.channels.c13.capacity = 1000000
agent.channels.c13.transactionCapacity = 1000

agent.sinks.s11.type         = FILE_ROLL
agent.sinks.s11.channel      = c11
agent.sinks.s11.sink.directory = /path/to/storage/s11
agent.sinks.s11.sink.rollInterval = 300

agent.sinks.s13.type         = FILE_ROLL
agent.sinks.s13.channel      = c13
agent.sinks.s13.sink.directory = /path/to/storage/s13
agent.sinks.s13.sink.rollInterval = 300
```